Set Subscribed status in SMS Marketing column
Currently when using the API "add member to list", and by setting status to subscribed, it only sets the "Email Marketing" column as "Subscribed". Is there any way to use the API to also set the "SMS Marketing" column to "Subscribed" as well?
I've read the API documentation, and their SMS Marketing pages, didn't see anything that would allow me to set the SMS Marketing subscription status in the API.

Yes you are correct. I was stuck on the same problem and I have found that as of now SMS Phone number field is not supported by Marketing API.
https://mailchimp.com/help/import-sms-marketing-contacts/#:~:text=At%20this%20time%2C%20the%20SMS%20phone%20number%20field%20isn%E2%80%99t%20supported%20with%20the%20Mailchimp%20Marketing%20API.

